# UIStoryboards and UITabBarController in iOS 7

Tags: ios6, uitabbarcontroller, ios7, uistoryboard, xcode5

In this app created using the iOS 6 SDK, I used this method described in [this](http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.com/2012/05/uistoryboards-and-uitabbarcontroller.html) article to modularize my storyboards. Basically what it does is, it creates a `UITabBarController` programatically and embed each storyboard as a tab in it.

This was working fine in iOS 6 but in iOS 7, it seems to have gone awry. When I run it, the app kind of *freezes*. Cannot tap on tabs to switch to them and all. Even the controls like buttons inside tabs don't receive taps.

The worst part is it doesn't even throw any errors or warnings. No deprecated APIs has been used in this either. I have no idea why this isn't working.

I have contacted the author who wrote the article and informed him about this issue but I haven't received any reply from him yet. I thought of asking here on SO in the meantime.

I have created a project demonstrating this issue and uploaded it [here](http://www61.zippyshare.com/v/28648629/file.html). Its created using Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.1. When you run it in iOS 6, it works fine but in Xcode 5, iOS 7, it doesn't.

I know its not a straight forward programming question but I'd appreciate if someone could take a look at it and give me a suggestion on how to rectify this issue.

Many thanks

Comment: why do you split your storyboard like this? Why do not create the tabbar in storyboard?

Comment: @null Its a pretty big app. So I wanted to break it down to modules so that in the long run, its easy to maintain. Having one tabbar with many many scenes is too messy.

Comment: valid, but I am talking about finding better way of splitting your app so your `tabbarcontroller` will be in the main storyboard, maybe creating segues to `UINavigationControllers` and push your sub storyboards VC's into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the -setUpTabBasedAppWithTabs:block: method, you are using this line:

```
[UIWindow new]
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
[[UIWindow alloc] init];
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

If you change that to something like:

```
[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]
```

Then this works correctly. Probably the window is up in the upper right corner, but not clipping the subviews, which lets them draw but prevents them from interacting with touches.

There are a couple of other confusing things in play in this demo though that may not be present in your real application. The main storyboard is still set in the info.plist/project editor.This means that your application has another window behind the one you are creating with an instance of some of your view controllers on it.

Comment: Wow I can't thank you enough! You're right. I just created this demo in a hurry just to display the issue. In my real app, I have set the correct storyboards in the info.plist. Thanks a lot again :)